# MySQL fastest way to query rows

Tags: php, mysql

My problem is that i don't yet have a good server to test this on but i'd like to know if it faster to use:

```
$sqlgetg = "SELECT assignments.id FROM assignments LEFT JOIN userassignments ON assignments.id = userassignments.assignmentid WHERE userassignments.userid = '" . $row['id'] . "' AND userassignments.assignmentid = '" . $assignmentid . "'";
```

or

```
$sqlgetg = "SELECT NULL FROM assignments LEFT JOIN userassignments ON assignments.id = userassignments.assignmentid WHERE userassignments.userid = '" . $row['id'] . "' AND userassignments.assignmentid = '" . $assignmentid . "'";
```

Since i have to check if there even is an assigment for the user with assignment id of x? I don't need anything else but this: *if(mysqli_num_rows($resultgetg) > 0)*? In both cases phpMyAdmin gave me the row number that i wanted. (I checked it with 
 without WHERE and it still worked.)

**EDIT:**
[I don't know how and why NULL works but it does...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cThk.png)

Comment: Either way, you should be using prepared statements. And indexes.

Comment: Unless NULL is a column name, the second statement shouldn't work...

Comment: @Leah well... https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cThk.png i don't know...

Comment: It's just showing NULL the same number of times as the result records...

Comment: @Leah that is not the point... *if(mysqli_num_rows($resultgetg) > 0)* takes NULL as an input. I just needed to know which one is faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select any static value "from" a table if you just want to count the rows returned... `SELECT NULL` or `SELECT 42` or whatever.   But both of your strategies are in fact suboptimal, because they require unnecessary work by the server and unnecessary network traffic and unnecessary handling of the result set that you are only planning to discard.

If counting rows is what you want, then **actually do that**. you should `SELECT COUNT(*) AS how_many_rows ...` and let the server count the rows and return a single row with a single column ("how_many_rows" -- make up your own alias) containing the count.

Comment: So using COUNT would just recognize the rows instead of trying to find data from them and this would be optimal for the server?

Comment: It should be optimal for server, client, and network.  Also, there is no need for the left join... no need for an inner join, either...  You only need the count from the `userassignments` table.  If you have a unique index on (userid, assignmentid) in that that table, the optimizer should go right to it, count the rows, return the values.  Data must be read in order to be counted but the index would be a covering index, thus minimizing the actual number of bytes actually read from disk.